# Ruby on Rails : How to have conditional sender email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, sender

I am using rails4, I need to change the from email address of my Action Mailer based on a condition. But it still takes the default from email address. How to get this working?

```
 class MailerController < ActionMailer::Base
   before_filter :get_tenant
   default from: "#{ENV['TENANT_EMAIL']}" if $tenant == 'mytenant'


   def get_tenant
     $tenant = 'mytenant'
   end
 end
```

I have mailerclass which inherits from MailerController....

> ERROR: An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the
>   message smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address.

Comment: use a mail interceptor: http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Comment: Can you make sure that if $tenant == 'mytenant' is always true ?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation, change the 'from' inside mail method.

```
  def tenant?
    is_it_my_tenant_logic
  end 

  def from
    tenant? ? MailerController.default[:from] : "hiro@metaverse.com"
  end

  def a_mailer_method         
     mail(:from => from, :to => "yt@realworld.com" ,  :subject => "I have logged in")
  end
```